# Multiple Python scripts and external software

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I started few months ago programming and am using Python as programming language. I'm working on Parametric Modelling of Composite Materials.
Basically, I create Python scripts to send commands to a finite-element software (MSC Marc) so that the FE model is automatically built. This is done by importing the Python script into the software (clearly only one file can be imported).

I'd like to automatise this process building a GUI so that users can directly insert the parameters in the GUI.

At the moment I have 2 GUIs (2 scripts) in which one of these gets and elaborates the parameters inserted and then sends them to the second GUI. Now, all the information from these 2 GUIs must be included in the Python script of the model itself (thus, in total 3 scripts).

I'm wondering whether is there any way to make just one script incorporating these three scripts?

I hope the problem has been well explained.

Thank you very much for your time and support.
Vincenzo

Comment: Sure, use classes to build GUI parts, and then build them like lego pieces in the importing script.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I figured out that classes is the way to go. However, the issue is a little bit more complex than that described.

Comment: You can always [edit] to describe better. If you're stuck somewhere you can ask about it in [so] with a [mcve] prepared for the isolated issue.